# CreateProcess failed in C

Tags: c, process, createprocess

i'm trying to create a process using the following code:

```
void GenerateCommandLine( char *commandLine, 
                          int maxLength, 
                          const char *imageTitle) {
    const char * COMMAND_LINE_TEMPLATE = "AnalyzeImage.exe --image_file %s";
    sprintf_s(  commandLine, 
                maxLength, 
                COMMAND_LINE_TEMPLATE, 
                imageTitle 
    );
}

int AnalyzeCurrentImage(char* imageTitle) {
    STARTUPINFO         startupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    DWORD               exitCode = MAXINT;
    char                commandLine[ MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH ];

    commandLine[ 0 ] = '\0';
    InitVariables( &startupInfo, &processInfo );
    GenerateCommandLine( commandLine, MAX_ELEMENT_LENGTH, imageTitle );
    printf( "-----------command line is: %s\n", commandLine );


    // Start the AnalyzeImage process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,       // No module name (use command line)
        commandLine,                // Command line
        NULL,                       // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,                       // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,                      // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,                          // No creation flags
        NULL,                       // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,                       // Use parent's starting directory 
        &startupInfo,   // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &processInfo )  // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }
    printf("here!!!");
    // Wait until AnalyzeImage process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE );

    GetExitCodeProcess( processInfo.hProcess, &exitCode );
    printf( "------------ Exit Code: %d\n", exitCode );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( processInfo.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( processInfo.hThread );
}
```

when i run this program from the command line i get the following:

> "-------command line is: AnalyzwImage.exe --imgage_file img000.jpg
>   CreateProess failed <2>"

do you have and idea why the create process is failing?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Error code 2 is [File Not Found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so `CreateProcess` is unable to find AnalzwImage.exe.  It is either not in the current directory or in the system path.  Try using the full path to AnalzwImage.exe.

Answer (score 0):

The code 2 returned by GetLastError() means **ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**.

Simply put, *AnalyzwImage.exe* could not be found.
You should either include the absolute path to the executable in the command line, or make sure that the current working directory at the time *CreateProcess* is called is the directory where AnalyzwImage.exe is located.